# if database id number changes update data on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, if-statement

I have a number(the id) on a page (Data2.php) linked to my database.
If that number changes I want the page to refresh. But this doesn't seem to work

---

### I have tried this:

#### in the head onload [`(document).ready(function(...`]:

```
$.get("Data2.php", function (data2) {
    var id_number = data2;
    $(".old").html(id_number);
});
```

#### and on a 1 second interval:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.get("Data2.php", function (data3) {
        var new_id_number = data3;
        $(".new").html(new_id_number);
    });

}, 1000);
```

#### And then I want this if statement to always be running:

```
if ($('.new').text() !== $('.old').text()) {
    $('.old').replaceWith($('.new').text());
    $.get("Data.php", function (data) {
        $(".data").html(data);
    });
    var elem = document.getElementById('data');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

---

*Side question:* Does the if statement perform in that order? Because I don't want to scroll until the new data is loaded

---

So basically... If the number in the 1 second loop changes: get new data **then** scroll to bottom

Comment: Anything that you don't want done until data is loaded by AJAX should be done in the AJAX callback function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the if statement "always running". You need to put it in your interval. Also, yes, the if statement performs the actions in that order, but it will not wait for the `$.get()` query to finish before scrolling, because `$.get()` is asynchonrous. If you want to wait for it to load before scrolling, just put the scroll event inside the `$.get()` callback.

```
$.get("Data.php", function (data) {
    $(".data").html(data);
    var elem = document.getElementById('data');
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Should all that I have coded now work for when there is a change on the database? Unfortunately I don't have access to my ftp at the moment so can't test it.

Comment: @user2768038 You'll still have to put the entire `if` statement inside the original `$.get()` block that calls Data2.php. After that it should work, but of course I haven't seen the rest of your code so I can't be sure.

Comment: Thank you. It sucks that I can't try it on JsFiddle!

Comment: @user2768038 actually I think there's a way to simulate server calls in jsFiddle. But anyway, just test it out when you get the chance, and if there's any problems just come back here and we'll help you out :)

Comment: You can't get me excited like that and not tell me! But don't bother if you dont have time :) Cheers.